# Why is the Size treated differently when defined as a parameter vs index?

Tags: agda

I have a question regarding some code which uses mutual inductive/coinductive data types and sized types.

```
module Ts where

open import Codata.Thunk using (Thunk; force)
open import Size using (Size; ↑_; ∞; Size<_)
open import Level using (Level)

private
  variable
    a : Level
    A : Set a

record L∞ (A : Set a) (i : Size) : Set a

data L (A : Set a) (i : Size) : Set a where
  []  : L A i
  _∷_ : A → L∞ A i → L A i

record L∞ A i where
  coinductive
  field force : {j : Size< i} → L A j
open L∞

♯_ : ∀ {i} → L A i → L∞ A i
♯ l = λ where .force {j} → {!l!}

-- Goal: L {A.a} A j
-- Have: L {A.a} A i
-- ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
-- j   : Size< i
-- l   : L {A.a} A i
-- i   : Size  (not in scope)
-- A   : Set A.a  (not in scope)
-- A.a : Level  (not in scope)

record L▴∞ (A : Set a) (i : Size) : Set a

data L▴ (A : Set a) : Size → Set a where
  []  : ∀ {i} → L▴ A i
  _∷_ : ∀ {i} → A → L▴∞ A i → L▴ A i

record L▴∞ A i where
  coinductive
  field force : {j : Size< i} → L▴ A j
open L▴∞

♯▴_ : ∀ {i} → L▴ A i → Thunk (L▴ A) i
♯▴ l = λ where .force {j} → {!l!}

-- Goal: L▴ {A.a} A j
-- Have: L▴ {A.a} A i
-- ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
-- j   : Size< i
-- l   : L▴ {A.a} A i
-- i   : Size  (not in scope)
-- A   : Set A.a  (not in scope)
-- A.a : Level  (not in scope)
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/raduom/4c15349c1ccd5864ae08b2ed2d4157b8

The difference between the two definitions is how I add the `Size` type in the inductive definition. At first, I add it as a type parameter, and in the second definition as an index.

The question is: Why does Agda accept the term in the first hole, but not the one in the second?